# ndepend - CQLinq Find types used as type params to 3rd party generic method

Tags: ndepend, cqlinq

I'm messing around with CQLinq and was trying to write a query to find the types in my project that are used as generic type params to a 3rd party generic method.

To be more specific, we use a 3rd party library called AutoMapper which has a static generic method, `Mapper.CreateMap<T1, T2>()`. Is it possible to write a query to find which types from my code are used as params to the CreateMap method?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not yet possible with CQLinq, since generic type params aren't resolved yet. You can vote for this feature here: http://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/4919844-be-able-to-check-if-a-type-is-implementing-a-gener

Comment: Thanks for the response...I voted and commented with my specific use case if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Roly, that will certainly helps